# Runbook deployment on Azure Stack

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-stack

Please help me with any document or link to how to deploy a Runbook on Azure Stack. I know we can do it in azure portal though. But I am not getting the exact procedure how to proceed in Azure Stack. We have public cloud where we  have the policy applied , so that it will behave like a stack. But when I try to create an automation account policy is disallowing to create the automation account. Hence I am skeptical now how to create an automation account and in turn deploy a Runbook in azure stack.As an alternative we are also trying out Visual Studio to create ARM template and deploy runbooks. Please suggest if anybody has any pointers any other way to do workflow automation in azure stack.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Azure automation is currently not supported on Azure Stack. This is already known to the Automation team and it would be helpful if you can up vote on this feedback as well: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/32099044-bring-azure-automation-and-dsc-to-azure-stack

Answer (score 1):

You create a log analytic workspace in azure and link that to the stack. that way you can create an automation account and enable inventory, update management and maybe runbooks.